# Removal of two homotopically non trivial open sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let M be a compact connected manifold. If you remove two open sets which are not homotopically trivial (i.e not homotopic to a point) then is the remaining set not connected? It seems to be the case for Torus for instance and it is easy to see that it does not work for removing just one open non trivial set. If the answer is affirmative is there are a more direct way to see this without using too much technology from algebraic topology?

update: By the answer below I see that I need to restrict to certain special cases. If you consider for instance when $M= \mathbb{T}^n$, it seems to be true only when $n=2$.

Answer (score 2):

This is very not true: Remove for example two circles that go around different holes in any genus $g$ surface $g>3$. There is a long exact sequence in homology that describes what is happening: the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Originally Poincare discussed something that you are thinking about, the maximal number of circles what can be removed to get a connected space. I believe this notion is not used much anymore, but instead we use homology.

I also think you need to describe what you mean with homotopically non-trivial, see for example

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Wada

Comment: I see. What about only torii of different dimensions? By homotopically non-trivial I mean that it is not homotopic to a point.

Comment: I guess in two torus it is more or less evident by inspection since any non trivial loop is homotopic to one of the circles that go ground the torus and if you remove two such circles, one at each two different points you see that you disconnect the torus. And in higher dimensions you can produce examples that do not disconnect it.

Comment: Sina, there are many more loops on the two torus that are not homotopic to a point